# F# double click on file creates a copy in VS

Tags: visual-studio, f#, editor

If I double click on a source file in Visual Studio F# project and accidentally slightly move the mouse even a tiny bit down (a few pixels suffice), then VS "renames" the file into a copy.

For example file `SomeSource.fs` becomes `Copy of SomeSource.fs`. The original file at that point "disappears" and the copy is added at the end of the project. The issue happens on all computers that I use and only in F# but not in C#.

It seems that there should some setting in VS, which tells it to do that. How to disable that thing?

Thanks.

Comment: That looks much more like a bug in the Visual F# tools than something that is in any way intended.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev but I'm not seeing this behaviour though. Have you replicated this in your environment?

Comment: @s952163 Yes, I've seen that too.

Comment: I can also verify; been bugging me for months. I'll throw a bounty on this when I can...

Answer (score 5):

Seems bug to me. Created just bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/327630/f-file-drag-in-solution-explorer-cause-file-being.html.

Hopefully, we get it to fix soon.

Btw Visual Studio has very nice bug report feature integrated: upper right corner => send feedback => report problem.

Comment: Problem not solved, but this is the closest thing to a solution here, and bounty will expire if I don't use it... enjoy.